# The ignite docker keeps restarting automatically. Error cause :IgniteCheckedException: WAL history is too short

Tags: java, ignite

After the virtual machine where my ignite docker service is located was rebooted, this error occurred :IgniteCheckedException: WAL history is too short, and because my docker-compose file has an automatic restart set, my ignite service keeps restarting automatically. Does anyone know what the problem is or what's causing it? Below is the ignite log of an automatic restart.

Apache Ignite Version:2.11.1
JVM_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx3584m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -DIGNITE_QUIET=true -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC

```
[03:23:35,136][WARNING][main][G] Ignite work directory is not provided, automatically resolved to: /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work
[03:23:35,145][WARNING][main][G] Consistent ID is not set, it is recommended to set consistent ID for production clusters (use IgniteConfiguration.setConsistentId property)
[03:23:35,253][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] 

>>>    __________  ________________  
>>>   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/  
>>>  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/    
>>> /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/   
>>> 
>>> ver. 2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147d
>>> 2021 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
>>> 
>>> Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org

[03:23:35,264][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Config URL: file:/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/config/default-config.xml
[03:23:35,282][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] IgniteConfiguration [igniteInstanceName=null, pubPoolSize=8, svcPoolSize=8, callbackPoolSize=8, stripedPoolSize=8, sysPoolSize=8, mgmtPoolSize=4, dataStreamerPoolSize=8, utilityCachePoolSize=8, utilityCacheKeepAliveTime=60000, p2pPoolSize=2, qryPoolSize=8, buildIdxPoolSize=1, igniteHome=/opt/ignite/apache-ignite, igniteWorkDir=/opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work, mbeanSrv=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@18ce0030, nodeId=934defcd-dafc-4759-a60e-723a8a9e7b6d, marsh=BinaryMarshaller [], marshLocJobs=false, daemon=false, p2pEnabled=false, netTimeout=5000, netCompressionLevel=1, sndRetryDelay=1000, sndRetryCnt=3, metricsHistSize=10000, metricsUpdateFreq=2000, metricsExpTime=9223372036854775807, discoSpi=TcpDiscoverySpi [addrRslvr=null, addressFilter=null, sockTimeout=3000, ackTimeout=0, marsh=null, reconCnt=10, reconDelay=2000, maxAckTimeout=600000, soLinger=0, forceSrvMode=false, clientReconnectDisabled=false, internalLsnr=null, skipAddrsRandomization=false], segPlc=STOP, segResolveAttempts=2, waitForSegOnStart=true, allResolversPassReq=true, segChkFreq=10000, commSpi=TcpCommunicationSpi [connectGate=org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.ConnectGateway@37858383, ctxInitLatch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@4e268090[Count = 1], stopping=false, clientPool=null, nioSrvWrapper=null, stateProvider=null], evtSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.eventstorage.NoopEventStorageSpi@1bb266b3, colSpi=NoopCollisionSpi [], deploySpi=LocalDeploymentSpi [], indexingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.indexing.noop.NoopIndexingSpi@355ce81c, addrRslvr=null, encryptionSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.encryption.noop.NoopEncryptionSpi@29647f75, tracingSpi=org.apache.ignite.spi.tracing.NoopTracingSpi@3315d2d7, clientMode=false, rebalanceThreadPoolSize=1, rebalanceTimeout=10000, rebalanceBatchesPrefetchCnt=3, rebalanceThrottle=0, rebalanceBatchSize=524288, txCfg=TransactionConfiguration [txSerEnabled=false, dfltIsolation=REPEATABLE_READ, dfltConcurrency=PESSIMISTIC, dfltTxTimeout=0, txTimeoutOnPartitionMapExchange=0, deadlockTimeout=10000, pessimisticTxLogSize=0, pessimisticTxLogLinger=10000, tmLookupClsName=null, txManagerFactory=null, useJtaSync=false], cacheSanityCheckEnabled=true, discoStartupDelay=60000, deployMode=SHARED, p2pMissedCacheSize=100, locHost=null, timeSrvPortBase=31100, timeSrvPortRange=100, failureDetectionTimeout=60000, sysWorkerBlockedTimeout=10000, clientFailureDetectionTimeout=5000, metricsLogFreq=60000, connectorCfg=ConnectorConfiguration [jettyPath=/config/jetty.xml, host=null, port=11211, noDelay=true, directBuf=false, sndBufSize=32768, rcvBufSize=32768, idleQryCurTimeout=600000, idleQryCurCheckFreq=60000, sndQueueLimit=0, selectorCnt=2, idleTimeout=7000, sslEnabled=false, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null, sslFactory=null, portRange=100, threadPoolSize=8, msgInterceptor=null], odbcCfg=null, warmupClos=null, atomicCfg=AtomicConfiguration [seqReserveSize=1000, cacheMode=PARTITIONED, backups=1, aff=null, grpName=null], classLdr=null, sslCtxFactory=null, platformCfg=null, binaryCfg=BinaryConfiguration [idMapper=null, nameMapper=BinaryBaseNameMapper [isSimpleName=false], serializer=null, compactFooter=true], memCfg=null, pstCfg=null, dsCfg=DataStorageConfiguration [sysRegionInitSize=41943040, sysRegionMaxSize=104857600, pageSize=0, concLvl=0, dfltDataRegConf=DataRegionConfiguration [name=Default_Region, maxSize=1073741824, initSize=268435456, swapPath=null, pageEvictionMode=DISABLED, pageReplacementMode=CLOCK, evictionThreshold=0.9, emptyPagesPoolSize=100, metricsEnabled=false, metricsSubIntervalCount=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, persistenceEnabled=true, checkpointPageBufSize=0, lazyMemoryAllocation=true, warmUpCfg=null], dataRegions=DataRegionConfiguration[] [DataRegionConfiguration [name=500MB_Region, maxSize=524288000, initSize=104857600, swapPath=null, pageEvictionMode=DISABLED, pageReplacementMode=CLOCK, evictionThreshold=0.9, emptyPagesPoolSize=100, metricsEnabled=false, metricsSubIntervalCount=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, persistenceEnabled=true, checkpointPageBufSize=0, lazyMemoryAllocation=true, warmUpCfg=null]], storagePath=/data/local/db, checkpointFreq=180000, lockWaitTime=10000, checkpointThreads=4, checkpointWriteOrder=SEQUENTIAL, walHistSize=20, maxWalArchiveSize=1073741824, walSegments=10, walSegmentSize=67108864, walPath=/data/local/db/wal, walArchivePath=/data/local/db/wal/archive, metricsEnabled=false, walMode=LOG_ONLY, walTlbSize=131072, walBuffSize=0, walFlushFreq=2000, walFsyncDelay=1000, walRecordIterBuffSize=67108864, alwaysWriteFullPages=false, fileIOFactory=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.file.AsyncFileIOFactory@10959ece, metricsSubIntervalCnt=5, metricsRateTimeInterval=60000, walAutoArchiveAfterInactivity=-1, writeThrottlingEnabled=true, walCompactionEnabled=false, walCompactionLevel=1, checkpointReadLockTimeout=null, walPageCompression=DISABLED, walPageCompressionLevel=null, dfltWarmUpCfg=null, encCfg=org.apache.ignite.configuration.EncryptionConfiguration@34f7cfd9, defragmentationThreadPoolSize=4], snapshotPath=snapshots, activeOnStart=true, activeOnStartPropSetFlag=false, autoActivation=true, autoActivationPropSetFlag=false, clusterStateOnStart=null, sqlConnCfg=null, cliConnCfg=ClientConnectorConfiguration [host=null, port=10800, portRange=100, sockSndBufSize=0, sockRcvBufSize=0, tcpNoDelay=true, maxOpenCursorsPerConn=128, threadPoolSize=8, selectorCnt=4, idleTimeout=0, handshakeTimeout=10000, jdbcEnabled=true, odbcEnabled=true, thinCliEnabled=true, sslEnabled=false, useIgniteSslCtxFactory=true, sslClientAuth=false, sslCtxFactory=null, thinCliCfg=ThinClientConfiguration [maxActiveTxPerConn=100, maxActiveComputeTasksPerConn=0]], mvccVacuumThreadCnt=2, mvccVacuumFreq=5000, authEnabled=false, failureHnd=StopNodeFailureHandler [super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], commFailureRslvr=null, sqlCfg=SqlConfiguration [longQryWarnTimeout=3000, dfltQryTimeout=0, sqlQryHistSize=1000, validationEnabled=false], asyncContinuationExecutor=null]
[03:23:35,282][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Daemon mode: off
[03:23:35,282][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] OS: Linux 4.19.283-1.ph3 amd64
[03:23:35,283][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] OS user: root
[03:23:35,283][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] PID: 1
[03:23:35,284][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Language runtime: Java Platform API Specification ver. 1.8
[03:23:35,284][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] VM information: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_212-b04 IcedTea OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.212-b04
[03:23:35,285][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] VM total memory: 3.5GB
[03:23:35,285][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Remote Management [restart: off, REST: on, JMX (remote: off)]
[03:23:35,285][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Logger: JavaLogger [quiet=true, config=null]
[03:23:35,285][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] IGNITE_HOME=/opt/ignite/apache-ignite
[03:23:35,286][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] VM arguments: [-XX:+AggressiveOpts, -Xms1024m, -Xmx3584m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -DIGNITE_QUIET=true, -Duser.timezone=UTC, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC, -XX:+DisableExplicitGC, -DIGNITE_HOME=/opt/ignite/apache-ignite]
[03:23:35,286][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] System cache's DataRegion size is configured to 40 MB. Use DataStorageConfiguration.systemRegionInitialSize property to change the setting.
[03:23:35,286][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Configured caches [in 'sysMemPlc' dataRegion: ['ignite-sys-cache']]
[03:23:35,289][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] 3-rd party licenses can be found at: /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/libs/licenses
[03:23:35,458][INFO][main][IgnitePluginProcessor] Configured plugins:
[03:23:35,459][INFO][main][IgnitePluginProcessor]   ^-- None
[03:23:35,459][INFO][main][IgnitePluginProcessor] 
[03:23:35,460][INFO][main][FailureProcessor] Configured failure handler: [hnd=StopNodeFailureHandler [super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]]]
[03:23:35,801][INFO][main][TcpCommunicationSpi] Successfully bound communication NIO server to TCP port [port=47100, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, selectorsCnt=4, selectorSpins=0, pairedConn=false]
[03:23:35,802][WARNING][main][TcpCommunicationSpi] Message queue limit is set to 0 which may lead to potential OOMEs when running cache operations in FULL_ASYNC or PRIMARY_SYNC modes due to message queues growth on sender and receiver sides.
[03:23:35,805][WARNING][main][TcpCommunicationSpi] Failure detection timeout will be ignored (one of SPI parameters has been set explicitly)
[03:23:35,813][WARNING][main][NoopCheckpointSpi] Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
[03:23:35,842][WARNING][main][GridCollisionManager] Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
[03:23:35,843][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Security status [authentication=off, sandbox=off, tls/ssl=off]
[03:23:35,874][WARNING][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failure detection timeout will be ignored (one of SPI parameters has been set explicitly)
[03:23:35,892][INFO][main][TcpDiscoverySpi] Successfully bound to TCP port [port=47500, localHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, locNodeId=934defcd-dafc-4759-a60e-723a8a9e7b6d]
[03:23:35,895][INFO][main][PdsFoldersResolver] Successfully locked persistence storage folder [/data/local/db/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0]
[03:23:35,896][INFO][main][PdsFoldersResolver] Consistent ID used for local node is [16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0] according to persistence data storage folders
[03:23:35,896][INFO][main][MaintenanceProcessor] Resolved store directory for node persistent data: /data/local/db/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0
[03:23:35,932][INFO][main][CacheObjectBinaryProcessorImpl] Resolved directory for serialized binary metadata: /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work/db/binary_meta/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0
[03:23:36,212][INFO][main][FilePageStoreManager] Resolved page store work directory: /data/local/db/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0
[03:23:36,232][INFO][main][FileWriteAheadLogManager] Resolved write ahead log work directory: /data/local/db/wal/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0
[03:23:36,232][INFO][main][FileWriteAheadLogManager] Resolved write ahead log archive directory: /data/local/db/wal/archive/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0
[03:23:36,269][INFO][main][FileHandleManagerImpl] Initialized write-ahead log manager [mode=LOG_ONLY]
[03:23:36,316][INFO][main][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Configured data regions initialized successfully [total=6]
[03:23:36,338][INFO][main][IgniteSnapshotManager] Resolved snapshot work directory: /opt/ignite/apache-ignite/work/snapshots
[03:23:36,338][INFO][main][IgniteSnapshotManager] Resolved temp directory for snapshot creation: /data/local/db/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0/snp
[03:23:36,408][WARNING][main][IgniteH2Indexing] Serialization of Java objects in H2 was enabled.
[03:23:36,712][INFO][main][ClientListenerProcessor] Client connector processor has started on TCP port 10800
[03:23:36,794][INFO][main][GridTcpRestProtocol] Command protocol successfully started [name=TCP binary, host=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, port=11211]
[03:23:37,117][INFO][main][GridJettyRestProtocol] Command protocol successfully started [name=Jetty REST, host=/0.0.0.0, port=8080]
[03:23:37,185][WARNING][main][IgniteKernal] System property will override environment variable with the same name: IGNITE_QUIET
[03:23:37,185][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Non-loopback local IPs: 10.13.5.2
[03:23:37,185][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] Enabled local MACs: 02420A0D0502
[03:23:37,193][INFO][main][CheckpointMarkersStorage] Read checkpoint status [startMarker=/data/local/db/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0/cp/1687686533662-419a9b30-9fb9-4946-b470-739783622216-START.bin, endMarker=/data/local/db/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0/cp/1687686533662-419a9b30-9fb9-4946-b470-739783622216-END.bin]
[03:23:37,200][INFO][main][PageMemoryImpl] Started page memory [memoryAllocated=100.0 MiB, pages=24814, tableSize=1.9 MiB, replacementSize=3.0 KiB, checkpointBuffer=100.0 MiB]
[03:23:37,201][INFO][main][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checking memory state [lastValidPos=WALPointer [idx=94, fileOff=40257029, len=527421], lastMarked=WALPointer [idx=94, fileOff=40257029, len=527421], lastCheckpointId=419a9b30-9fb9-4946-b470-739783622216]
[03:23:37,217][INFO][main][FilePageStoreManager] Cleanup cache stores [total=0, left=0, cleanFiles=false]
[03:23:37,218][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Exception during start processors, node will be stopped and close connections
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: WAL history is too short [descs=[org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@5f, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@60, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@61, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@62, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@63, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@64, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@65, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@66], start=WALPointer [idx=94, fileOff=40257029, len=527421]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager$RecordsIterator.init(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:2801)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager$RecordsIterator.access$900(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:2672)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.replay(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:971)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.replay(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:938)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.read(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:926)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.performBinaryMemoryRestore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:2101)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.readMetastore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:845)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.notifyMetaStorageSubscribersOnReadyForRead(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:3237)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1300)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1787)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1172)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1066)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:952)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:851)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:721)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:690)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:367)
[03:23:37,221][SEVERE][main][IgniteKernal] Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: WAL history is too short [descs=[org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@5f, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@60, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@61, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@62, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@63, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@64, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@65, org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileDescriptor@66], start=WALPointer [idx=94, fileOff=40257029, len=527421]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager$RecordsIterator.init(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:2801)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager$RecordsIterator.access$900(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:2672)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.replay(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:971)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.replay(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:938)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.wal.FileWriteAheadLogManager.read(FileWriteAheadLogManager.java:926)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.performBinaryMemoryRestore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:2101)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.readMetastore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:845)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.notifyMetaStorageSubscribersOnReadyForRead(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:3237)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1300)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2141)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1787)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1172)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1066)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:952)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:851)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:721)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:690)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353)
    at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:367)
[03:23:37,222][WARNING][main][IgniteKernal] Attempt to stop starting grid. This operation cannot be guaranteed to be successful.
[03:23:37,226][INFO][main][GridTcpRestProtocol] Command protocol successfully stopped: TCP binary
[03:23:37,235][INFO][main][GridJettyRestProtocol] Command protocol successfully stopped: Jetty REST
[03:23:37,257][INFO][main][FilePageStoreManager] Cleanup cache stores [total=0, left=0, cleanFiles=false]
[03:23:37,265][INFO][main][IgniteKernal] 

>>> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite ver. 2.11.1#20211220-sha1:eae1147dd1cd625cc229098489be8d208f6cabcc stopped OK
>>> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Grid uptime: 00:00:02.961
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the crash, your WAL files are now corrupted.

The most straightforward solution will be - clean the persistence on the affected node and rebalance the data.

If you don't care about the possible data inconsistency, try deleting only WAL-related ones first:

```
/data/local/db/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0/cp/ 
/data/local/db/wal/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0
/data/local/db/archive/node00-16d8b0a6-20b9-42e3-8b88-147ec1b5ccb0
```

Comment: Thanks, the last thing I did was delete the work directory and restart the ignite service, and it worked fine. I wanted to ask what was causing the WAL file problem, as the ignite service on several of my VM had this error.

Comment: I suppose it's because of `LOG_ONLY` WAL_MODE which is default. https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/persistence/native-persistence#wal-modes

Comment: I think it was just an unlucky system crash. Changing it to `FSYNC` should help to survive OS crashes, but can also affect performance in some way. In addition, consider spreading your VMs to different physical instances if you want a better robustness.

Comment: ok,thanks.I will try to use FSYNC  mode.